# Unable to interact with Instagram login fields

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I'm having trouble interacting with the [Instagram login page](https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/) using Java Selenium. I've tried using `Actions` like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/");
WebElement login_elem = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
WebElement pw_elem = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(login_elem).click();//Also tried this with a 'moveByOffset()'
action.sendKeys(username);
action.moveToElement(pw_elem).click();
action.sendKeys(password);
action.perform();//nothing happens

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("_t38eb _ov9ai")).findElement(By.tagName("button"));//element isn't visible
element.click();//Element isn't visible
```

and I've also tried using `ExpectedConditions`:

```
public void login( ) {
    driver  = new SafariDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/");

    //Element isn't visible: waitElement times out. I've checked all the parts of the xml string, and it works until the '/input' at the end
    waitElement("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/input[@class = '_ph6vk _jdqpn _o716c']",20);
    waitElement("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/input",20);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    Rest(3,true);       
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + username);
}

public void waitElement(String element, int time){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, time);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(element)));
}

public void Rest(int seconds, boolean msg){
    try {
        if(msg)
        Thread.sleep(seconds*1000);         
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and it definitely doesn't work with the normal `findElement()` -> `sendKeys()`:

```
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/");
Thread.sleep(5000);//Wait for page to load
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.className("_ph6vk _jdqpn _o716c"));//find the text box
input.sendKeys(username);//ElementNotVisibleException is thrown here.
```

How do I enter strings into the form fields?

EDIT: also tried the following:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/");
/*line 13*/ new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[name='username']"))).sendKeys("AlbertLiu");
    }
}
```

Here's the error I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: input[name='username'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
Capabilities {applicationCacheEnabled: true, browserName: safari, cleanSession: true, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: true, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, version: 13604.5.6, webStorageEnabled: true}
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)
at selenium.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

Using `By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")`, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //input[@name='username']] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)
at selenium.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a wait for the first element, the page should be loaded and you can access all elements. You only need to wait for the username field to be visible... not sure why clickable doesn't work. I used the wait and locators below and it worked fine for me.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[name='username']"))).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.='Log in']")).click();
```

Comment: Hi Jeff! Which WebDriver are you using? I'm using the Safari WebDriver, I copied your code and it gave me a `TimeoutException` at the second line in that code block.

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is an IFRAME that these fields are in? I'm using Chromedriver. I don't think there is a Safari for Windows any more so can't test it.

Comment: I honestly don't know what an IFRAME is. I think they're part of an element called "react-root", and a "form" element, but I don't have very much experience in HTML so idk much about that

Comment: It's an `<IFRAME>` HTML element. It will contain other HTML and you have to switch into it using Selenium to be able to see the HTML contained inside. You should be able to find the username field and look up the HTML DOM and see what elements are above it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: OK, gotcha, no it's not in an iframe. There's an iframe on the page but the login fields aren't in it.

Comment: Something weird is definitely going on with your machine... I'm not sure what it is. The site is being rendered differently due to your location or maybe driver issue? Have you fully updated your browser and got the current driver version matched up?

Comment: I'm using Safari 11.0.3, the latest version of eclipse, and Java JDK 8, on a practically new MacBook Pro. Safari has a native WebDriver since version 10, so I should be covered there. I just looked a little closer at the HTML, and I found that the classnames for the elements enclosing the login field change when I click on the login text field, and then again when I type stuff in. Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: I see the classnames changing too... it's adding a border to the field you are filling in but shouldn't affect the answer I've given due to the locators I've used. You might try exploring locators in the dev console in Safari... does it have one? For example, in Chrome and FF you can type `$$("input[name='username']")` in the console and it performs a CSS selector search for matching elements. Try that and see if it comes up with any matches.

Comment: So I just updated my OS, and it looks like everything works now until it tries to click on the login button, where it throws a `ElementNotVisibleException`. I tried adding a wait, and it threw a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: I got around it using Actions, so everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

To send text to the `<input>` field with help text as **Phone number, username, or email** you can remove the `Thread.sleep(5000)` and induce [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as [elementToBeClickable](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as follows :

```
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[name='username']")))sendKeys("AlbertLiu");
//or
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']]")))sendKeys("AlbertLiu");
```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB! I just tried that, and for some reason I'm still getting a `TimeoutExcpetion`. Here's the error message: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: input[name='username'] `

Comment: @AlbertLiu Can you update the question with your exact code block and the error stack trace please?

Comment: yep! I added the code in, along with the error stack trace.

Comment: @AlbertLiu Can you try with the _xpath_ option updated within my answer and let me know the status?

Comment: Yeah, I added the exception I got to the end of the question. I don't really know xpath syntax, but I tried both `By.xpath("//input[@name='username']]")` and `By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")`. Both had `TimeoutException`

Comment: @AlbertLiu You need to remove the extra `]` before the _xpath_ ended as in `']]"`.

Comment: I did, see previous comment. Both had same exception, the first one had a longer stack trace that I assume had to do with the parsing of the xpath string